# Nativescript vue image not showing off

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Why my images not showing off ?

Label is displaying url properly but image not show.
Why its not displaying? need to add something ?
It was working before.
If I added normal Image with src plain text like this its showed

```
  <StackLayout>
    <Button text="Make new screensot" />  
    <Button text="Load images" @tap="loadImages()" />
    <Label v-if="!loadedImages" text="Not loaded images" textWrap="true" />


     <RadListView v-else for="(item,index) in imagesS"
               itemHeight="100">
    <v-template>
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Label :text="item.url"></Label>
        <Image :src="item.url" stretch="aspectFill" class="screenshots" />
      </StackLayout>
    </v-template>
  </RadListView>

   <ActivityIndicator class="activity-indicator" :busy="indicatorS"></ActivityIndicator>



  </StackLayout>
```

I added css but not working too

```
 .screenshots{
    height:100;
    width:100;
  }
```

**methods**

```
methods: {

  loadImages() {
    console.log('starting loading images');
     this.indicatorS = true;
    axios.get(this.jsonUsers + this.ID + '/images')
    .then((response) => {

          const imgCount = response.data.length;
          console.log("count- " + imgCount)

          var imagesArr = response.data;

          console.dir("images - " + response.data[0].url)


          this.$store.commit('setImages',imagesArr);
          console.log('images fully loaded');  
          this.$store.commit('setLoadedImages');
          this.indicatorS = false;

    })

  } 

 }
```

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyJkW.jpg)

Comment: Can you maybe create a playground this? https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in the playground. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=aKZ2wm.

I think the URLs you are using are not really for the images.https://imgur.com/a/AkEg8vy This is what you are using, that is not a url for the image its a URL for a web page.

Now if I go to the page and take the image URL https://i.imgur.com/78j1SJr.jpg. It's working fine.